Pyspark getting date from struct field with dollar sign in it
Using Pyspark and this is a pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
I am trying to get to this value "entrytimestamp.$date" (can be null) from a Mongo JSON file that has this schema. I can get everything else but this field. Any suggestions?
 root
 |-- ENTRY: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- log: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- activity_fields: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ENTRYTIMESTAMP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PART_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SESSIONID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- entrytimestamp: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- $date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)

The field contains:
$date="2024-12-01 00:00:00.047+0000"
edit: I should mention this is a Mongo json file.

How did I not remember this just used a string literal
df_mpip = df.filter(df.entrytimestamp['$date'].between(*dates))

